# The proper method to get tokio runtime handle based on current running environment

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

What's the idiomatic way to get a tokio runtime handle based on the current running environment?

- For methods already run in tokio runtime, I want to use `Handle.try_current().unwrap()` to get the current one.
- For methods not run in tokio, I can create a new one: `Runtime::new().unwrap().handle()`.

However, when I wrote my code as:

```rust
fn get_runtime_handle() -> Handle {
    match Handle::try_current() {
        Ok(h) => h,
        Err(_) => Runtime::new().unwrap().handle().clone(),
    }
}

async fn a_async() -> Result<()> {
    ....
}

fn a() -> Result<()> {
   let handle = get_runtime_handle();
   handle.block_one (async { a_async().await; })
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    a();

    Ok(())
}
```

and call `tokio::fs::read_dir` inside, the code crash with `Error: Custom { kind: Other, error: "background task failed" }`.

And when I substitute `handle.block_on` with `Runtime::new().unwrap().handle().block_on` in main, the code runs successfully.

I suppose my `get_runtime_handle` function is problematic, what's the right way to express this?
The full runnable code is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc91f2f9fad4de2561f7456037fd4fc7).

Besides, when the method `get_runtime_handle` is running inside a tokio runtime, other unit tests from the project complains:

```sh
thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. 
This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the
current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the lifetime of your new runtime, it is dropped at the end of the get_runtime_handle(). You should return the runtime if the function create one.

```rust
use tokio::runtime::{Runtime, Handle};

fn get_runtime_handle() -> (Handle, Option<Runtime>) {
    match Handle::try_current() {
        Ok(h) => (h, None),
        Err(_) => {
              let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
              (rt.handle().clone(), Some(rt))
            }
    }


fn main() {
    // let _ = Runtime::new().unwrap();
    let (handle, rt) = get_runtime_handle();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but the second problem still exists: since I was implementing `fn a()` using `a_async()` using block_on, when `a()` was called inside a `tokio::main`, the `panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. 
This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block .....shows. How should I deal with that?

Comment: It is because when you use `tokio::main` the main function is inside a runtime, and like the error says you can't run a runtime inside a runtime. `block_on` is an entry point for a runtime, I am pretty sure `tokio::main` use it to run the `async main`. what you want to use in this case is `spawn` or `spawn_blocking`.